# Installing Ganache GUI in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install Ganache GUI on my Ubuntu 19.04, and didn't find the way to install it.
I tried downloading the AppImage from the truffle site trufflesuite.com/ganache and did the following to make it executable and run:

```
chmod a+x <downloaded file name>
./<file name>
```

and a number of other combinations for the first one such as:

```
chmod 777 <file name>
chmod 777 *.AppImage
```

etc. but could not get it done. And I have the "make it executable" and all other read and write permissions enabled.

I even tried cloning the ganache project from github via this link:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache.git
And doing `npm install` and then `npm start` but this doesn't work either because there seems to be no start script in the package.json file.

Also, I'm not sure what to add in the scripts, because normally I'd set it to `./bin/www` but there is no folder `bin` here.

Can anyone suggest me more ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I tried the one as provided in the accepted answer of this link: :)

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/ganache-gui-installation-error